# how to get total amount as textview in custom layout in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am getting an array values price qty is edittext i set as default as 1. I want multiplay as price and qty and setttext as total...

I try this code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    int x;
    integer[] a;
    public static ArrayList<String> arr1=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> itemprice=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Bitmap> itemimage=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    public Context Context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    String total;

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arr,ArrayList<String>     price,ArrayList<Bitmap> image) 
    {
        Context=context;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        arr1=arr;
        itemprice=price;
        itemimage=image;
        System.out.println(itemprice);
        System.out.println("arr: " + arr.size());


    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr1.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr1.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
        System.out.println(arr1.get(position));

          final  ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selecteditemlistview, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.textViewSelectedText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectedtext);
                holder.price=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemprice);
                holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemimagge);
                holder.qty=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectqty);
                holder.total=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalamount);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else 
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            String amount=holder.qty.getText().toString();


            holder.textViewSelectedText.setText(arr1.get(position));
            holder.price.setText(itemprice.get(position));
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(itemimage.get(position));
            holder.total.setText();

            return convertView;     
        }

        class ViewHolder      
        {
            TextView textViewSelectedText = null;
            TextView price=null;
            ImageView image=null;
            EditText qty=null;
            TextView total=null;
        }      
 }
```

my edittext code

```
 <EditText
      android:id="@+id/selectqty" android:maxLength="3" android:text="1"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selectitemprice" >
```

I want to multiplay price and qty settext as total... please how to do ..help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
then use someThing like: 

 textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

 price=Integer.parseInt(price[position]);
int qut=Integer.parseInt(s.getText().toString());
int total=(price*qut);
holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        }
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```